# converting date from given string

Tags: string, powershell, datetime

I need to identify this string containing Date

> 20151110171937.050162+060

It's `CreationDate` property of object `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process`. I need to use it as input to `New-TimeSpan` cmdlet. Therefore, it should be valid `[DateTime]` object, but I don't know how to convert it.

Comment: try casting [System.DateTime]

Comment: `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process|ForEach-Object {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationDate)}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell extend each WMI object with two methods `ConvertFromDateTime` and `ConvertToDateTime` which allows you to convert date and time between WMI string and .NET `[DateTime]` representations. This methods actually are just references to `[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]` static methods `ToDmtfDateTime` and `ToDateTime`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you :-).

Answer (score 0):

The part before the decimal is "20151110171937"

Or 2015-11-10 17:19:37

There's your date/time stamp.  Ignore the rest.

Comment: "I need to use it as input to New-TimeSpan cmdlet" you don't seem to comply with the OP's requirements : )

Answer (score 0):

The string "20151110171937.050162+060" is a WMI datetime format and is a equivalent to [CIM_DATETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) datatype with following format (yyyymmddHHMMSS.mmmmmmsUUU) where;

- mmmmmm   Six-digit number of microseconds in the second (000000 through
  999999). Your implementation does not have to support evaluation
  using this field. However, this field must always be present to
  preserve the fixed-length nature of the string.
- s    Plus sign (+) or minus sign (-) to indicate a positive or negative
  offset from Coordinated Universal Times (UTC).
- UUU  Three-digit offset
  indicating the number of minutes that the originating time zone
  deviates from UTC. For WMI, it is encouraged, but not required, to
  convert times to GMT (a UTC offset of zero).

The UUU is of significance since it does change for you local time zone. You can test this by changing your local time zone and running for example

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate
```

You can covert using PeterSerAl mention or by this shortcut for a one off

```
([WMI]'').ConvertToDateTime((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate)
```

But note there's a bug with ConvertToDateTime() and [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime() in Powershell, it does not respect local time zone and will give you the **wrong date**. Analysis [here](http://metadataconsulting.blogspot.ca/2017/04/Powershell-ConvertToDateTime-Method-Definition-and-Implementation-error.html), but this short and long of it that you have to **reboot the Powershell shell or ISE for this to work**.